# How pass regex in PIPE to split a string in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass regex format from HTML and want to split a string on all special characters and spaces except "_".

> Ex : #abc_xyz defgh // output #abc_xyz
>
> Ex : #abc@xyz defgh // output #abc
>
> Ex : #abc%xyz&defgh // output #abc
>
> Ex : #abc$xyz*defgh // output #abc

I am using below code

> split.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'splitString'
})
export class splitString implements PipeTransform {
transform(value:string, [separator]):string {
    let reg = new RegExp (separator);
    let splits = value.split(separator);
    if(splits.length > 1) {
   // FOR LOOP - Check index [0],[1].. are not empty. If value is Empty then Don't return.
        for( let i=0; i<splits.length;i++){ 
            if(splits[i].length > 0){
                return splits[i];
            }
        }
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

> myComponent.html
>       {{ data | splitString:"(?:^|\s)\#(\w+)"}}

Comment: Okay. So what is the issue here ?

Comment: Issue is I dont know how to pass regex here? If i directly passing regex in html then it is throwing an error

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: It breaks my html dom rendering.

Comment: I am only able to pass single character only eg. {{ data | splitString:"#"}} . If I pass multiple characters then it doesn't split accordingly

Answer (score 0):

May be below one will help you.

```
{{ data | splitString:["(?:^|\s)\#(\w+)"] }}
```

Comment: @AmbujKhanna I tried on angular 6 not sure for angular 4. [Angular 6 Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1kycf)

Comment: In your demo, It is not splitting value. It is also showing up same value i.e. **#abc@xyz** It should show value **#abc** only

Comment: @AmbujKhanna Yes i didn't transformed value i just helped to how pass regex string to the pipe. Do you want to split string by regex and just take index 0 string from array after split ?

Comment: Thats an issue. Split doesn't work. Would you please update your demo for me.

Comment: @AmbujKhanna I can't give guarantee that it can be done but will try once.

Comment: I am only able to pass single character only eg. {{ data | splitString:"#"}} . If I pass multiple characters then it doesn't split accordingly

Comment: @AmbujKhanna Dyanmic regex not working but i am able to split using regex in pipe directly [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1kycf)